# Can't find delete button in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to frontend development and I have a problem.

In the code downloaded from this site ([develoteca.com](http://develoteca.com/image-select-con-jquery-para-un-dropdown-con-imagenes-desplegables/)) I can't find any reference to the "x" button which appears next to a selected user (as shown on the image below)
[image]

I would like to change its colour but more importantly, I want to understand where the code that behind it resides.

Comment: there is no delete x button on that page

Comment: I guess OP means the small "x" to remove items from the list, that looks like the code is in the choosen JS external library used in that example.

Comment: yes, i am looking for it but can't find

Comment: "x" you are looking is seems part of an image. So, you could not change its color. Do change an image

Comment: Have you tried using your browsers "inspect" function (right click on the HTML element and then click "inspect"), you can see what element it is and even see the CSS selectors to modify it.

Comment: A little advice for you that doesn't address your main question... If you're new to front end development you should learn native javascript before learning a library like JQuery.

Comment: @xander thank you so much, I have complete forgotten about this, it helped  me

Comment: @DanielLane thank you too for advice, I will start with native javascript

Comment: @MarinaM DOM (Document Object Model) elements are held in memory by your browser as an object model and are available to javascript. You can use the DOM selection APIs built into web browsers to select elements. Take a look at the MDN for further information. Generally as a frontend dev the MDN is the best place for native javascript and browser API documentation. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector and the examples given.

Comment: @DanielLane okay, thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the "x" you're refering to is part of the external JavaScript libary [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Assuming your example code is based on the "multiple select" function of chosen, you should be able to customize the style of the close button with the CSS selector

```
.chosen-container .search-choice-close
```